# Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent error in sitecore logs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am getting following ERROR in the sitecore logs and from there on wards logs stopped recording. could some one please let me know what is the fix for the ERROR.

i am using sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150223)

```
"ManagedPoolThread #7 01:14:32 INFO Job started:      Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #7 01:14:32 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException
Message: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'LuceneIndex'.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.VerifyNotDisposed()
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex.CreateSearchContext(SearchSecurityOptions securityOptions)
at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.IndexQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.IndexQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.QueryableProxy`1.GetEnumerator()
at Sitec    ore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent.Execute()"
```

Comment: Someone already had similar issue: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1742 . If nothing linked there helps you, you may need to contact with Sitecore Support

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

The Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent is a special agent introduced for List Manager functionality. This job is intended to automatically unlock the created lists. By default it is configured to run with interval of 10 seconds, that is why you experience so frequent messages in your log.
So having such number of rows is not a results of any problems.

This functionality **has been rewritten in Sitecore 8.0 Update-6**, and merged into **Sitecore 8.1 Update-1**. In recent versions, it uses hooks instead jobs, and number of log records is reduced, See the [release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2080%20Update6/Release%20Notes):
The number of log entries created by the execution of the UnlockContactListsAgent agent has now been reduced. (59585, 433183) 
Please consider upgrading of your installation.
In your revision, you could add a filter to the default logger to ignore the specified lines:

```xml
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="UnlockContactListsAgent"/>
    <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
  </filter>
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
</appender>
```